# How to import and export SharedPreferences file?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, dropbox-entry

I'm trying to export and import the SharedPreferences file from my device i asked here the question before and i saw a example code of someone but i have problem with the"Entry" :
it given me:

> The type DropBoxManager.Entry is not generic; it cannot be
>   parameterized with arguments `<String, ?>`

```
private boolean saveSharedPreferencesToFile(File dst) {
        boolean res = false;
        ObjectOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dst));
            SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MySharedPreferences.MY_TEMP, 1);

            output.writeObject(pref.getAll());

            res = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) {
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    private boolean loadSharedPreferencesFromFile(File src) {
        boolean res = false;
        ObjectInputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(src));
                Editor prefEdit = context.getSharedPreferences(MySharedPreferences.MY_TEMP, 1).edit();
                prefEdit.clear();
                Map<String, ?> entries = (Map<String, ?>) input.readObject();
                for (Entry<String, ?> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
                    Object v = entry.getValue();
                    String key = entry.getKey();

                    if (v instanceof Boolean)
                        prefEdit.putBoolean(key, ((Boolean) v).booleanValue());
                    else if (v instanceof Float)
                        prefEdit.putFloat(key, ((Float) v).floatValue());
                    else if (v instanceof Integer)
                        prefEdit.putInt(key, ((Integer) v).intValue());
                    else if (v instanceof Long)
                        prefEdit.putLong(key, ((Long) v).longValue());
                    else if (v instanceof String)
                        prefEdit.putString(key, ((String) v));
                }
                prefEdit.commit();
            res = true;         
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong `Entry` object.

You want `Map.Entry<K, V>`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html